# Generar un array de numeros aleatorios que no se repitan en java

Tags: java, random

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int numeros[]=new int [4];
    int minimo = 1;
    int maximo = 5;
//Genera, comprueba e introduce los numeros en el array si la comprobación es correcta
    for (int i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++) {
        int num = Generar(minimo,maximo);   
        //Aqui es donde falla, siempre sale true.
        if(Comprobar(numeros,num)==true){
            numeros[i] = num;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(numeros[i]);
    }

}
public static int Generar(int minimo, int maximo){
    Random  rnd = new Random();
    int num = (minimo + rnd.nextInt((maximo + 1) - minimo));
    return num;
}
public static boolean Comprobar(int numeros[], int num){
    boolean igual = false;
    for(int i = 0; i<numeros.length;i++){
        if(numeros[i] != num){ 
            igual = true;
        }
    }return igual; 
}
```

Comment: Que tal Milayton, ¿Qué es lo que pasa con el código? ¿Tiene algún problema de compilación o una excepción? ¿Genera resultados erróneos?

Comment: el probelama esta en el ciclo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bien, debes hacer algunas modificaciones al codigo

Cuando haces uso del metodo Comprobar, el ciclo que estableces con For, se efectua 4 veces ya que "numeros.length" siempre sera igual a 4, y esto no es necesario (o de hecho da un comportamiento inesperado en el programa), de hecho solo seria necesario comprobar, los valores que hasta ese momento esten asignados en el array, ahora para saber esto, pasariamos un tercer argumento a este metodo, la variable "i". Con esto tendremos que modificar el metodo, en especifico se deben invertir los operadores booleanos (ya que si no lo hacemos el primer valor asignado a "num" retornara false. El metodo quedaria asi:

```
public static boolean Comprobar(int numeros[], int num, int i){
 boolean igual = true;
 for(int j = 0; j<i; j++){
    if(numeros[j] == num){
            igual = false;
       }
   }return igual; 
}
```

Ahora cuando mandas a llamar al metodo Comprobar, solo consideras, la situacion en la que se devolvio un true, pero en caso de un false deberiamos volver a asignar una cantidad a "num", puede ser asi para volver a efectuar el mismo paso del ciclo:

```
if(Comprobar(numeros,num,i)==true){
                numeros[i] = num;
} else i--;
```

Observa el tercer argumento en el metodo.
Como ultimo comentario considero que la formula que asignas a "num", seria suficiente con esto:

```
int num = minimo + rnd.nextInt(maximo);
```

Suerte.

Comment: Ahora si funcionó a la perfección @L3WIS, Gracias por la ayuda. =)

Answer (score 0):

mira, la cuestion es simple, no debes meter un ciclo dentro de otro ciclo, solo basta con comprobas una sola vez:

```
public static boolean Comprobar(int numeros[], int num){
//declaras una variable boolena y la inicia en falso
    boolean igual = false;
    for(int i = 0; i<numeros.length;i++){
//recorres el array normal preguntado a cada vuelta si son iguales
        if(numeros[i] == num){ 
//si en algun momento llegan a ser iguales entonces la variable cambia de valor
            igual = true;
        } 
    }
//y ya solo retornas la variable con su valor
    return igual; 
}
```

**ACTUALIZACION** se cambiar `if(numeros[i] == num)`
espero te sirve, me cuentas bro....

Comment: Muchas gracias por contestar, pero nada, lo actualicé con tu codigo y aun me sigo dando numeros repetidos. =)

Comment: cambia la condicion `if(numeros[i] == num)`